# import html file in joomla article

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to import one html file in my joomla article. I wrote following script

```
function importHTML() {
    var obj = jQuery("[id^='importHTML_']").attr('id');
    if(null != obj && 'undefined' != obj) {
        var importClass = obj.split('_')[1];
        $("." + importClass).load("./htmls/" + importClass + ".html"); 
    }

}
```

and added following HTML tag in my joomla article

```
<div id="importHTML_differentiator" class="differentiator"> </div>
```

and placed my HTML file at

> "template_folder/htmls/differentiator.html"

but nothing is happening. this HTML is not displaying on my page. What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Where did you add the javascript code?

Comment: in my custom js file. I am able to see my js file in firebug

Comment: Is this not fundamentally misunderstanding the purposes and benefits of Joomla itself since you can import/include html content in an article without need for JS at all using Joomla - there are dozens of plugins freely available for including a custom html module in an article for example. Or, if you must, you can even use a php include command.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996985/how-to-include-an-external-php-file-into-a-joomla-article/18998041#18998041